# Jquery Error - Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "settings", validator is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a mvc application page using unobtrusive jquery. When i submit the form, it does not hit the controller action and im getting this error on Firefox console, Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "settings", validator is undefined.

What might be the common reason for this?

cshtml code

```
@model NationsAlpha.Models.AccountOpening.AOProfile.AccountProfile
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveNewProfile", "AccountOpening", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "tab1info", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { id = "frmProfile" }))
{ 
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form">
    <h4>Account Profile</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", true)   

    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Attachments</div>
        <div class="panel-body">

            <div class="row hidden-xs hidden-sm  hidden-md"> 
                <div class="col-md-3  col-sm-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.xBatchNo)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.xBatchNo, new { placeholder = "Batch No", @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.xBatchNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-2 display:table-cell;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="hidden-xs">&nbsp</label>
                        <div>
                            <button id="btnAcquireAttachments" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-info">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download" aria-hidden="true"></span> Acquire Batch
                            </button>
                            <button id="btnDisposeAttachments" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-danger">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove Batch
                            </button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    @Html.Partial("AOProfileCreateAttachmentList", new NationsAlpha.Models.AccountOpening.AOProfile.AccountProfileUploadDocumentType())
                </div> 
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-11 col-md-1">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

C# controller

```
 public ActionResult SaveNewProfile(AccountProfile model)
    {
        if (validateApplicants())
        {

            string MandateId = saveManadate(model, user.userId);                 

        }

        return PartialView("AOProfileCreate", model);
    }
```

Comment: Request you to please share code

Comment: Seems like you are getting error in JavaScript validator function Can you please share that also. Like on submit method

Comment: @prathameshk73 No i haven't use any js method here. Ajax.BeginForm fires the controller event